# How to calculate the integral of this function $\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}$

Tags: integration

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}dx$

Like this, how to calculate?

**Edit:**
Thank you, the solution is clear. I have a more question. We call the function as "circular function", which satifies $\pi(f)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dxf(x)\equiv\pi$. We treat $f(x)=\pi g(x)$ as one kind of circular functions, where $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dxg(x)=1$. And any other circular functions besides the two discussed?

Comment: Well what did you try?

Comment: I have tried Taylor expansion. It does't work as well as subsection integration. I think it needs a useful transformation.

Comment: I have found the same question, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\,dx &=& 2 \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\,dx \\ &=& 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{x}\,dx \\ &=& 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}\,dx \\&=& 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin z}{z}\,dz = \color{red}{\pi}.\end{eqnarray*}$$
We exploited parity, integrated by parts and substituted $2x=z$ to get the well-known Dirichlet's integral.